# VBA splicing cells separated by comma

Tags: excel, vba, row, splice

I am really new to VBA coding.

Problem I have is this:

B60, D60, F60, H60 (etc) cells have different values in this format: x, y, z
(x, y and z can be numbers 0-10)
I'd like to splice this so it becomes:

```
B60 = x
B61 = y
B62 = z
D60 = x2
D61 = y2
D62 = z2
```

etc.

I've found this code:

```
Dim objRegex
Dim Z
Dim Y
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim tempArr() As String
Dim strArr
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegex.Pattern = "^\s+(.+?)$"
'Define the range to be analysed
Z = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp)).Value2
ReDim Y(1 To 2, 1 To 1000)
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(Z, 1)
'Split each string by ","
tempArr = Split(Z(lngRow, 2), ",")
For Each strArr In tempArr
lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
'Add another 1000 records to resorted array every 1000 records
If lngCnt Mod 1000 = 0 Then ReDim Preserve Y(1 To 2, 1 To lngCnt + 1000)
Y(1, lngCnt) = Z(lngRow, 1)
Y(2, lngCnt) = objRegex.Replace(strArr, "$1")
Next
Next lngRow
'Dump the re-ordered range to columns C:D
[a1].Resize(lngCnt, 2).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Y)
```

But this doesn't quite work for me. I only need row 60 to do this. I really tried editing this code, but I don't understand any of it... Can someone help me out please? It's really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick for you. Works only on row 60, and will not overwrite the existing values, so you can check for accuracy.  Will only work for 3 comma-separated values in each cell.

```
'Required declaration for the arrays to be 0-based in VBA.
Option Base 0

'Routine to split out the values and place them vertically under the original cell.
Sub SplitItOut()
    'Variable to hold the contents of the cell in question.
    Dim contents
    'Column number of the column to start searching for data in.
    Dim startColumn As Integer
    'Counter variable used to keep track of the current column.
    Dim columnCounter As Integer
    'Array to store the comma-separated values in, after they have been separated from their commas.
    Dim numArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    columnCounter = 0

    'Starting column is 2 which is "B".
    startColumn = 2
    'Read in the initial contents of "B60". Cells function is using (row 60, column 2) style notation.
    contents = Cells(60, startColumn).Value

    'Keep looping until there is nothing but an empty string in the contents variable.
    Do While contents <> ""
        'Split out the numbers in the cell and store them in an array.
        numArray = Split(contents, ",", -1)
        'Loop through the 3 entries in the array.
        For i = 0 To 2
            'Place each entry in successive rows below the original cell.
            'The Trim function is used to remove any potential extra spaces from the number.
            Cells(61 + i, startColumn + columnCounter).Value = Trim(numArray(i))
        Next
        'Move to the next column.
        columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
        'Read in its contents.
        contents = Cells(60, startColumn + columnCounter).Value
        'If the contents are empty, move to the next column.
        If contents = "" Then
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
        End If
        'If the next column is also empty, the loop will exit, otherwise it will continue with the new contents of the current column.
        contents = Cells(60, startColumn + columnCounter).Value
    Loop
End Sub
```

If you have a varying number of comma-separated values in each cell, you will need to change the line:

```
For i = 0 To 2
```

to

```
For i = 0 to Ubound(numArray)
```

**EDIT**

Fixed code to work with 1 blank column between each column of data.

Comment: Adding some comments to your code would surely help the OP (especially if he doesn't understand well the code he found) and your answer would then surely desserves upvotes

Comment: Wow, I almost figured out what the code meant without your comments. After you added the comments it became totally clear what you did. I tried it, and it works perfectly! Only thing I changed is columncounter + 1 to columncounter + 2, since I skip 1 column every time (this column is not empty but has different data). Thanks a lot, definitely very helpful.

Comment: @user1646031 glad to have helped.  You can mark this answer as the 'accepted' answer by clicking the check mark.    Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Stewbob: fellow excel users thank you for your commented code. You have made the world better :D - upvoted for the edit and commented code

Comment: @Stewbob. I hope you don't mind me bothering you with another (perhaps easy) question. Sometimes 2 columns are empty, but the data continues after those 2 empty columns. However, the loop will stop. I tried to define the last column as finalCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column but it's difficult to integrate this within your code.

Comment: Is this an option: Do while startColumn + columnCounter < finalCol

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. If there's an empty cell this error shows up: Subscript out of range at .Value = Trim(numArray(i))

Comment: @user1646031, With a non-regular pattern to the columns that contain the data you want, this becomes more difficult.  You would have to examine the contents of each column(cell) and figure out a test that would determine if it matches the type of data you want.  Otherwise, you would need to re-arrange your worksheet to put the data in a more predictable and regular arrangement.

Comment: @Stewbob. Thanks for your answer. I guess it's easiest to try and delete those empty columns. I will try that!